# How to check if an element that isn't in the DOM is visible with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, visible

It seems like elements that are not in the DOM are considered to be hidden, regardless of the CSS applied to those elements

for instance, putting the following in the Chrome console evaluates to `false`:

```
$('<div style="display: block;">i am a div</div>').is(":visible")
```

Is there any way to check if a detached element like the one above is visible or not. I don't just want to check that `display` css property is `block`.

Comment: shoudl be - `$('<div style="display: block;">i am a div</div>').find('div').is(":visible")`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but the simplest thing would be to attach it to check:

```
var $div = $("<div>");
$div.appendTo("body").is(":visible");
$div.detach();
```

If this check is prohibitive for you, you can check both the `display` and `visibility` CSS to check that they are not `none` and `hidden`, respectively, and that the `hidden` attribute is not set.   You could also do something like set `position: fixed; top: 100%` and do the above test.

EDIT: seems like jQuery's hidden check is:

```
jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) === "none"
|| !jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem )
```

So you could just get rid of the second line there to do an equivalent check.

Answer (score 1):

[**Sure you can**](http://jsfiddle.net/bevacqua/JTTg2/)

```
var foo = $('<div style="display: block;">i am a div</div>');
foo.appendTo('body');

var vis = foo.is(":visible");

console.log(vis);

foo.detach();
```

Not sure why you'd ever want to try this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<div style="display: block;">i am a div</div>').css("display")!="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element is not attached to a DOM then browser does not treat it as visible, because simply put it does not have a parent which might affect it's visibility also